# Como soluciono este Error en webpack

Tags: nodejs, api, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Este es el error 
ERROR in ./index.js
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYQqx.png) Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './index.css'

Este es mi 
index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from 'App';

Comment: Puedes poner el webpack.config que usas ?, lo mas probable es que no tengas un css loader

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tienes un link a un issue que se parece mucho a tu problema

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1470

debes tener style-loader en tu webpack.config

```
{
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' },
    ]
  }
}
```

y tenerlo instalado en tu node_modules

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader
```